# How to populate data from existing sqlite database to ListView with ImageView

Tags: java, android

I'm looking for a way to display data from the existing sqlite database that I created earlier using "DB Browser" into ListView. In the database there is a Logo / Image (Blob) column that I want to enter into the ListView. How can I do that?

I got the code below from the internet, but unfortunately this method cannot display images, only displays two lines in one row.

This is my main_activity changed to Home_Act..

```
    public class Home_Act extends AppCompatActivity {

        static final String DBNAME = "testing.db";
        static final String DBASSETPATH = "databases/" + DBNAME;
        static final String CHANNELTABLE = "Channel_Info";
        static final String KEY_NO = "No";
        static final String KEY_NAME = "Name";
        static final String KEY_CATEGORY = "Category";
        static final String KEY_LOGO = "Logo";

        ListView channelList;
        SQLiteDatabase mDB;
        SimpleCursorAdapter mSCA;
        Cursor mCsr;

        @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act_home);

    channelList = this.findViewById(R.id.channelList);
    mDB = openDB();



    if (mDB != null) {
        mCsr = mDB.query(CHANNELTABLE,
                new String[]{KEY_NO + " AS _id",
                        KEY_NAME, KEY_CATEGORY, KEY_LOGO
                },
                null,null,null,null,null);
        mSCA = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.mylist,mCsr,
                new String[]{KEY_NAME, KEY_CATEGORY, KEY_LOGO},
                new int[]{R.id.item, R.id.textView1, R.id.icon},0);

        mSCA.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder(){
            // Binds the Cursor column defined by the specified index to the specified view
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex){
                if(view.getId() == R.id.icon){
                    //...
                    String channelName = cursor.getString(3);
                    Home_Act.this.getResources();
                    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(channelName, "drawable", getPackageName());

                    //Option 1
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { //>= API 21
                        ((ImageView)view).setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(resID, getApplicationContext().getTheme()));
                    } else {
                        ((ImageView)view).setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(resID));
                    }

                    //Option 2
                    //((ImageView)view).setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(resID));

                    return true; //true because the data was bound to the view
                }
                return false;

            }
        });

        channelList.setAdapter(mSCA);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Unable to open Database.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }

    channelList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String Slecteditem = itemname[+position];
            channelName = Slecteditem;
            OpenDialog();
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Slecteditem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}

private SQLiteDatabase openDB() {
    String dbpath = this.getDatabasePath(DBNAME).getPath();
    if (this.getDatabasePath(DBNAME).exists()) {
        Log.d("OPENDB","Opening already existing Database");
        return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbpath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }
    InputStream is;
    byte[] buffer;
    FileOutputStream db;
    try {
        is =  this.getAssets().open(DBASSETPATH);
        buffer = new byte[is.available()];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("OPENDB","Unable to locate or buffer input from assets " + DBASSETPATH);
        return null;
    }
    // Just in case the databases directory doesn't exist create it.
    File dbmkdir = (this.getDatabasePath(DBNAME)).getParentFile();
    dbmkdir.mkdirs();
    try {
        db = new FileOutputStream(this.getDatabasePath(DBNAME).getPath());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("OPENDB","Unable to create outputstream for DB at path " + dbpath);
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception e2) {
        }
        return null;
    }
    try {
        db.write(buffer);
        db.flush();
        db.close();
        is.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("OPENDB","Failed to copy asset to DB");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbpath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}
```

The code above only shows 2 lines in 1 row, which I want to include the image on the left.

this is With Code Above, image not showing and there is no error.

[image]

and this is What I Want.

[image]

**EDIT :**

Now it's working as I want.
Number one, you must have your own layout which includes 2 TextView and 1 ImageView. with the .xml code as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textColor="#33CC33" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Number two, follow the code above.

Comment: where and how do you store your image data? is it an `Uri` stored in the database?

Comment: @pskink for second image (What i want) using Manual Method, i store the images in res/drawable folder.. for now in the database is blob type, maybe i will change to Uri/text to load the images if possible.

Comment: what excatly is a problem - te get image from the DB, or to show it in ImageView?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko if posible i want to add images to the left of each item. you can see "static final String KEY_LOGO = "Logo";" is blob type in database.

Comment: ok, but `what excatly is a problem - to get image from the DB, or to show it in ImageView?` `to add images to the left of each item` is too broad and consists of multiple steps. Which of them is the problem?

Comment: Verify if you having a problem in reading URL or showing images in a custom adapter view?

Comment: if it is a blob column so you can either extend `SimpleCursorAdapter` and override `setViewImage` method or use a `ViewBinder` and set it via `setViewBinder` method - you can read how it works by reading the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter)

Comment: i have edit my code, adding KEY_LOGO to mCsr and mSCA, but the logo/image not showing anywhere and there is no error. maybe the problem is simple_list_item_2 layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SimpleCursorAdapter` doesnt support image in `to`. And in your code

```
new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, mCsr,
                    new String[]{KEY_NAME, KEY_CATEGORY, KEY_LOGO},
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2}, 0);
```

you are passing 3 columns to 2 textviews which shows in UI without any exception. If you want to show image + textViews you need to create your own custom Adapter.

Or try to set it as below:

```
mSCA.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder(){
   /** Binds the Cursor column defined by the specified index to the specified view */
   public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex){
       if(view.getId() == R.id.your_image_view_id){
           String yourImageNameFromDb = cursor.getString(2);
           int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(yourImageNameFromDb , "drawable", getPackageName());

          ((ImageView)view).setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(resID));
           return true; //true because the data was bound to the view
       }
       return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: no, `SimpleCursorAdapter` does support `ImageView`s - read `SimpleCursorAdapter` official [documantation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter) - this is the first paragraph: *"An easy adapter to map columns from a cursor to TextViews or ImageViews defined in an XML file."*

Comment: take a look constructor description please https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter#SimpleCursorAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.database.Cursor,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D,%20int)

Comment: what does it have to do if `SCA` supports `ImageView` or not? and as I said it does support it, check the sources - https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/jb-release/core/java/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.java#158

Comment: it says about `to`param as following: "int: The views that should display column in the "from" parameter. These should all be TextViews. The first N views in this list are given the values of the first N columns in the from parameter. Can be null if the cursor is not available yet."

Comment: no, you can pass `R.id.myImaveView` as well in `to` array - did you see how `ImageView`s are handled by `SCA`? did you check the link I posted?

Comment: then why you are not passing it as a 3rd param? in your current implementation you are passing only textViews `new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2}`

Comment: did you notice I am not the original poster?

Comment: Ups sorry then let's wait for original poster's try

Comment: @Vasif thanks it works but... if ((ImageView)view).setImageDrawable(...); changed to ((ImageView)view).setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.xlogo)); all item have same image, that is not what i want. i am not really understand anyway.. but how can i have diferrent image for each item? and what i have to do to make it happen? adding new column in database or make logo column to type text or anything? i am trying to modify your code anyway, since i am not expert so it will take a long time..:D thanks

Comment: the code above should set each image new image file. you can save image file name in db (in logo column). For example if your image name is "test1.png", "test2.png" you save in db column as "test1", "test2" for corresponding row and then  and use it as my example (I edited that example)

Comment: i have problem with this line int resID = res.getIdentifier(yourImageNameFromDb , "drawable", getPackageName());.. "res" Qualifier must be an expression. i am trying new res, new resID (cannot resolve symbol 'getIdentifier), getResources() (Crash on play)..

Comment: @Vasif maybe you want to change your code before i accept this answer.